# Remove the caption on my Homepage allotted to an image without deleting the image itself

Tags: wordpress

I would like to remove the caption from an image on my home page which was originally used as a navigation tool.  I would like to keep the image on my home page but just remove the fonts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove caption from the image with the following two ways:

1. The caption will be inside a tag like `<caption></caption>` or `span` etc..
   so you can add css `display: none;` for that tag.
2. You can give `font-size: 0;` or `text-indent: -9999px;` to the image's parent class.